# Is there any way to print out the exact column name and value that lead to the record going into corrupt records in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have used permissive mode to catch corrupt records based on the schema, it works but I want to know the exact column of the said record which caused the record to go into corrupt records.

```
df = spark.read  \
.format("csv") \
.option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
.option("header", "true") \
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd HH.mm.ss") \
.option("dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd") \
.option("delimiter", ",") \
.option("escapeQuotes", "true") \
.option("multiLine", "true") \
.option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord","_corrupt_record") \
.schema(final_schema) \
.load(s3path)
```

Currently, I get the whole record in corrupt_records.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the column name but the reason why it was rejected can be seen by using badrecordspath instead of permissive + columnnameofcorruptrecord , using badrecords path generates a json with a path, reason and record schema which mentions the reason due to which record was rejected

```
df = spark.read  \
.format("csv") \
.option("header", "true") \
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd HH.mm.ss") \
.option("dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd") \
.option("delimiter", ",") \
.option("escapeQuotes", "true") \
.option("multiLine", "true") \
.option("badRecordsPath","<some path>") \
.schema(final_schema) \
.load(s3path)
```

Comment: It's worth to mention that it seems to be Databricks functionality only. This option is not mentioned in the regular spark csv docs - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html